# An analogue to Robinson's theorem for Kalmar-elementary functions

Tags: lo.logic

Julia Robinson proved that the family of all *unary computable total* functions is the smallest class containing $S$, $\mathrm{Exc}$, and closed under composition, addition and inversion of surjective functions. (Here $\mathrm{Exc}(x)=x-\lfloor\sqrt x \rfloor^2$, and the inversion of a surjection $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is $f^{-1}(m) ={}$the least $n$ such that $f(n)=m$.)

Raphael Robinson proved a similar result for the family of *unary primitive recursive* functions: it is the smallest class containing $S$, $\mathrm{Exc}$, and closed under composition, addition and iterations. These results are proved in Monk's book *Mathematical Logic*.

Is there a similar result for the family of *unary elementary* functions?

Comment: The question is too vague. What is a “similar result”? In particular, elementary functions are *defined* as the smallest class that contains some basic functions and is closed under composition, bounded summation, and bounded products. Why is that not enough for you?

Comment: I am not familiar with the proof of the results that you mention. However, giving this two results, I think that I have a natural conjecture of what an analogue for elementary functions could be.  Namely my conjecture would be that the class of all unary elementary functions is the least class containing, $S,\mathrm{Exc},\mathsf{exp}$ and  closed under compositions, additions, and bounded inversions. Here $\mathsf{exp}(x)=2^x$ and $g$-bounded inversion of $f$ is $x\longmapsto \min(\{g(x)\}\cup\{y\mid f(y)=x\})$.

Comment: Let me explain what I mean by  "similar result". The theorems I mentioned provide a definition of the collections of *unary* computable/primitive recursive functions. I was wondering if anyone is aware of a similar characterization for the *unary* elementary functions. The suggested conjecture is indeed natural.